# How can I have pagination and receive new messages simultaneously with Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am making a chat application in ReactJS using Firebase.

Everything works fine, but I ran into some trouble whilst trying to use pagination

I have looked into this and that worked fine: [Pagination using react-firebase-hooks](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/issues/13#issuecomment-572934099)
The problem is that once I send/load a new message it reloads the entire data and duplicates it.

Then afterwards I tried switching to the Realtime database using `useList` instead of `useCollection`

Using `useList` it sort of works, but it replaces the top element with the bottom one, and therefore removes already loaded information. So instead of appending the list, it's just adjusting the references.

I saw another method being used with two seperate lists, one for old messages and one for new messages. But this doesn't look like the most efficient solution...

[Other question: [Accepted Answer] using two seperate lists.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64594631/react-native-gifted-chat-with-cloud-firestore-pagination)

**Chat.js**

```
const users = [props.uid, auth.currentUser.uid]
users.sort()
const conversationReference = db.collection('conversations').doc(users[0] + "_" + users[1])
```

```
const queryFn = React.useCallback(() => {
    let q = conversationReference
        .collection('messages')
        .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
        .limit(20)
    return q
}, [props.uid])

const [[messages, queryLoading, error], more] = useFirestoreLoadMore(queryFn)
```

```
const sendChat = () => {
        if(message.length > 0) {
            chatReference.add({
                to: props.uid,
                from: auth.currentUser.uid,
                message: message,
                createdAt: new Date(),
            }).then((docRef) => {
                conversationReference.update({
                    lastChat: message,
                    lastActivity: new Date()
                }).then(() => {
                    setMessage('')
                })
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log("Error sending message")
            })
        }
    }
```

```
useEffect(() => {
        if(top && messages[messages.length - 1].data().message)
            more()
    }, [top])
```

`messages[messages.length - 1].data().message`*: using dummy document to indicate end of collection*

**useFirestoreLoadMore.js**

```
import {useCollection, useCollectionData, useCollectionOnce} from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore'

export const useFirestoreLoadMore = queryFn => {
    const [query, setQuery] = useState(null)
    const [last, setLast] = useState(null)
    const [data, setData] = useState([])

    const [qData, loading, error] = useCollection(query)

    useEffect(() => {
        setData([])
        setQuery(queryFn())
    }, [queryFn])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (qData && qData.query.isEqual(query)) {
            setLast(qData.docs[qData.docs.length - 1])
            //console.log("first: ", data.length, " | second: ", qData.docs.length)
            setData([...data, ...qData.docs])
        }
    }, [qData])

    const more = useCallback(() => {
        setQuery(queryFn().startAfter(last))
    }, [queryFn, setQuery, last])

    return [[data, loading, error], more]
}
```

**Question:** How do I paginate the `[messages]` of `useList` or `useCollection` (I'm open to both methods. Haven't fully decided which one suits best) whilst also being able to receive new messages?

Answer (score 1):

I settled on changing the `useFirestoreLoadMore`:

**useFirestoreLoadMore.js**

```
export const useFirestoreLoadMore = queryFn => {
    const baseValue = 20
    const increment = 100
    const [query, setQuery] = useState(null)
    const [limit, setLimit] = useState(baseValue)
    const [data, setData] = useState([])

    const [qData, loading, error] = useCollection(query)

    useEffect(() => {
        setData([])
        setQuery(queryFn().limit(limit))
    }, [queryFn])


    useEffect(() => {
        if (qData && qData.query.isEqual(query)) {
            setData([...qData.docs])
        }
    }, [qData])

    const more = useCallback(() => {
        setQuery(queryFn().limit(limit + increment))
        setLimit(limit + increment)
    }, [queryFn, setQuery])

    return [[data, loading, error], more]
}
```

It's not the most efficient way I assume. But I didn't see another way to maintain live updates regardless..